# How do I use url_for to not get a 405 error

Tags: python, flask

I am new to flask and trying to build a small web app, where a user types into a form in one page and then presses a button. The button should send us to a second page displaying certain data. The problem that I am having is that the button being is passed is causing a `405 error`.

This is my `app.py` file

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from forms import ScheduleForm
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'aae3d59542630a35356332ea6ca60652'

classes = [
    {
        'crn':'11111',
        'name':'class name 1',
        'meeting_time':'MWF 5:00-5:50'
    },
    {
        'crn':'2222',
        'name':'class name 2',
        'meeting_time':'MWF 6:00-6:50'
    }
]

@app.route('/')
def home():
    form = ScheduleForm()
    return render_template('home.html',title='Schedule Maker - Home', form = form)

@app.route('/schedule', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def schedule():
    return render_template('schedule.html',title='Schedule Maker - Schedule',classes=classes)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

My button is built with an anchor tag that has an href call like this

```
<a class="form-group" href= "{{ url_for('schedule') }}">
    {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
</a>
```

The form is just a SubmitField that was built using `FlaskForm` and `wtforms` like this

```
submit = SubmitField('Schedule')
```

The output is suppose to be the second page with a method name `schedule` but instead is

```
405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED
The method is not allowed for the requested URL.
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: to send form you have to use `<form action="URL" method="POST">`, not `<a href="URL">`

Comment: Can you match the both Schedule form template (schedule.html) and ```@app.route('/schedule', methods=['GET', 'POST'])``` this part have the same methods. You should use GET or POST for web forms, not both together.